# How to say "to start establishing a family"?

Tags: phrase-request

By these I mean when a person wants to be married with another person at first.

Would you please help me how to say these?

> difficulties in getting married
>
> difficulties in establish a family

....

Edited: By this I mean I have some problem that might be related to economic, or everything. Therefore, have I correctly written the following to explain that I have some problems to get married and start a family.

> I have difficulties settling down

Thanks

Comment: To me, "I have difficulties settling down" might be understood as: the person is too restless or reluctant to give up their freedom of living as a single, among other things. If you want to include that, it's fine. But if you want to say that you were willing to marry and **ran into an obstacle** you could say 'difficulties (in) getting married' (I agree with the other comment that "difficulties in establishing/to establish a family" might imply the inability to have children. There is a good list of collocations at [LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/difficulty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common phrase is "settle down". [It means](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/settle+down):

> To begin living a stable and orderly life.

So you could say:

> I want to settle down, and start a family.

This doesn't directly state that you are having difficulties starting a family, however it implies that you are frustrated that you haven't been able to settle down and start a family yet.

Comment: Note that in many contexts, "start a family" will be understood as meaning "having children".  And if you say "I am having trouble starting a family", that may be interpreted as meaning "I am infertile".